# Dar tamaño máximo a un input range en HTML5

Tags: javascript, html5

Buenas 
quisiera saber cómo se le da un valor máximo a un input range digitando el valor en un input text.
por ejemplo si quiero que el rango máximo sea de 70 primero debo digitar en el input text el valor para que al momento de deslizar el slider llegue hasta los 70 como rango máximo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el valor maximo debo primero digitarlo donde esta el 0 para que al momento de mover el slider llegue hasta el valor digitado.
aclaro que debe ser por el javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos he investigado un poco más y he elaborado este ejemplo con agularjs, y así es mucho mejor y justo como lo quería, gracias a todos por su ayuda. dejo demo por si alguien lo necesita
[DEMO](http://codepen.io/Jbs016/pen/GjdQQr)

**HTML:**

```
<html ng-app="simu">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-controller="SimuCtrl as control">                          
<input type="number" ng-model="input.i15" name="" >
<input type="number" name="" value="{{input.sc2.val}}" disabled="">
<input type="range" ng-model="input.sc2.val" min="{{input.sc2.min}}" max="{{input.i15}}" step="{{input.sc2.step}}">

</body>                     
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
angular.module("simu",[])
.controller("SimuCtrl",["$scope",function ($scope) {
    $scope.input={};
    $scope.input.i15 = 0;
    $scope.input.i16=0;
    $scope.input.sc1 = {
        val : 0,
    min : 0,
        step : 0.5
    }
    $scope.input.sc2 = {
        val : 0,
    min : 0,
        step : 0.5
    }
    $scope.input.sc3 = {
        val : 0,
        min : 0,

        step : 0.5
    }
    $scope.output = {
        o1:0,
        o2:0,
        o3:0,
        o4:0,
        o5:0,
        o6:0,
        o7:0,
        o8:0,
        o9:0,
        o10:0
    }
}]);
```

Comment: brother, si lo querías en Angular, lo hubieras dicho. Tu pregunta fue clara: HTML5 y JavaScript, nada más. Siguiente pregunta la realizas con mayor detalle. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

```js
var maxValue = document.getElementById("MaxValue");

var elemento1 = document.getElementById("MaxValue");
elemento1.addEventListener("change", function(){ 
  console.log('Valor del input: '+elemento1.value);
  var powerRanger = document.getElementById("PowerRanger");
  powerRanger.max = elemento1.value;
});

var elemento2 = document.getElementById("PowerRanger");
elemento2.addEventListener("change", function(){
 console.log('Valor del rango: ' + elemento2.value);
});
```

```html
<input id="MaxValue" type="number" min="0" step="1">
<br>
<input id="PowerRanger" type="range" min="0" step="1">
```

Referencia: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
Recomendado: http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/javascriptya/

Comment: Sinceramente, para preguntas sin código creo que no deberías responder con códigos enteros si no dar un camino para llegar a la solución. De esta manera, fuerzas al que pregunta a que se esfuerce y no obtenga un código con el típico copy-paste.

Comment: saludos @Error404 Entiendo tu punto de vista y también lo comparto, es muy rara la vez que pongo código apoyando a un usuario que no hace el intento. El usuario es nuevo para empezar, en segundo lugar sí se esfuerza por hacer funcionar lo que anda intentando, he visto sus otras 2 preguntas y él mismo se las ha respondido, motivo por el cual he colaborado con la respuesta. Espero me deje entender :D

Comment: No había visto su perfil la verdad. Entiendo que empezar es difícil, (yo tampoco me considero un experto ni mucho menos pero si con algo de soltura), y yo tampoco soy de poner código si en la pregunta no hay nada de código aunque siempre me pueden preguntar sobre como utilizar el código y yo les responderé sin preguntas. Buena respuesta de todas formas :D +1

Comment: Muchas gracias @fredyfx nuevamente por su gran ayuda y comprensión y de verdad que apenas estoy iniciando desde hace pocos días en el mundo de  javascript. Error404 gracias por su comentario.

Comment: @JBS No hay ningún problema. Otra vez te pediría que añadieras algo de código que hubieras probado antes si pudiera ser. Y no dudes en preguntar, es la mejor manera de aprender. Es difícil empezar pero luego te abre un mundo de posibilidades. Como dirían los ingleses... Happy coding :)

Comment: de nada hermano @JBS, estamos para servir, ambos enlaces que te he pasado en la respuesta son vitales! Dale con todo el power 2.0!!! Por cierto Error404, gracias :D

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
var range = document.querySelector('#idrange');
var text = document.querySelector('#idtext');
range.max = text.value;
```

asi por ejemplo

```js
function mostrar(){
  document.querySelector('#text3').value = document.querySelector('#range1').value;
}

function cambiar(){
  var range = document.querySelector('#range1');
  var text = document.querySelector('#text2');
  range.max = text.value;
}
```

```html
  <input type="text" id="text2" value="max">
        <input type="button" id="button1" value="cambiar" onclick="cambiar()">
        <input type="range" id="range1" max="10" min="0" step="1" onchange="mostrar()">
        <input type="text" id="text3" value="valor" readonly>
```